# PHP не отправляет данные в базу данных

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Отправляю данные с формы, которую заполняет пользователь, на базу данных через PHP. Данные собираю через JS, потом собираю все в PHP и пытаюсь отправить на PHP. Но данные по какой-то причине не уходят. 
Делал тестовые запросы на базу данных с фейковыми данными - и все отправлялось. Ошибку найти никак не могу, но есть подозрение, что проблема в .JS

PHP:

```
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['fname']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['lname']);
$start_adress = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['stadres']);
$end_adress = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['endadres']);
$Price = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['price_finalized']);
$CarriersQuant = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['amount_of_carriers']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['phone']);
$idgen = time();


// Attempt insert query execution
$post = "INSERT INTO Orders (OrderID, FirstName, LastName, StartAdress, EndAdress, Price, CarriersQuant, email, phone) VALUES ('$idgen' ,'$first_name', '$last_name', '$start_adress', '$end_adress', '$Price', '$CarriersQuant', '$email', '$phone')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $post))
{
    echo "Records added successfully.";
            print_r($post);
} else  
{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $post. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

.JS:

```
function calculateprice()
{
        var amount_of_carriers = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
        var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
        alert(email + phone);

        price_initial = 40; // Initial price of order
        price_per_km = 1.2; // Price per kilometer
        price_per_hour = 20; // Price per Hour
        price_per_carrier = 20; // Pricer per 1 carrier

        time_rounded = Math.round(MyTime/60); // Round time to hours 
        distance_rounded = (Math.round(MyDistance/100)/10); // Round meters to kilometers 

        price_finalized = price_initial + (time_rounded * price_per_hour) + (amount_of_carriers * price_per_carrier) + (distance_rounded * price_per_km);

        document.getElementById("pricetextbox").innerHTML = "Your price: " + price_finalized + " euro." + " " + "Your order ID: " + n + " " + fname + " " + lname;


        $.ajax({
            url: 'insert.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {endadres:endadres,stadres:stadres,amount_of_carriers:amount_of_carriers, price_finalized:price_finalized, lname:lname, fname:fname, email:email, phone:phone},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
      }) 

}
```

Comment: 1. учимся смотреть логи в консоле 2. смотрим ответ от php в dev tools 3. постим сюда

Comment: почитайте еще про подготовленные запросы и биндинг параметров.

Comment: @Nilsan логи в консоел чистые, ошибок там никаких нет. В этом вся проблема. Данные в JS точно существует, проверял каждый через alert. Если напрямую запустить .php, то данные дойдут до ДБ

Comment: скриншот бы логов, может у вас чекбокс и\х вывода выключен))

Comment: так а php чего вам отвечает смотрели?

Comment: проверь url и скрин devtools по данному запросу сюда скинь с респонсом и заголовками.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте откуда у вас берутся данные для первых двух параметров в ajax запросе

```
endadres:endadres,stadres:stadres
```

Похоже они у вас не объявлены. Это может привести к остановке работы js